# How to add newsletter functionality (just stable modules if possible)?

Tags: 7

I've searched a little and I needed to add newsletter functionality to a Drupal 7 installation. I've found Simplenews, which is in Beta version for Drupal 7 nothing more. I don't need anything really complicated, just these functionalities:

- Guest user can subscribe to newsletter by leaving their email address in a field
- Registered users can tick a checkbox in their profile to choose whether to receive newsletters
- Users can unsubscribe from newsletter by clicking a link in the newsletter
- A WYSIWYG editor for sending newsletters (but, I think this can be accomplished with the WYSIWYG module)

nothing more. If any of you tried the development version of Simplenews, please provide your experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) is really your only way of going. I have personally been holding off on it's implementation in 7 because of its state as well. More specifically, emails were not being sent (test ones were) and it's lack of mimemail support.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a module called [Newsletter](https://www.drupal.org/project/newsletter) which might be ok, have a more user centric UI (all the features are on a panels not spread out like in Simplenews). Newsletter can also handle multiple newsletter lists and also have a more complex form for collecting the data: e.g you can gather up the subscriber names, age, sex etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [MailChimp](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module. It's does what you described and it free for the first few members (can't remember how many users.)

> This module provides integration with [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/), a popular email
>   delivery service. The module makes it easy for website users or
>   visitors to control which of your email lists they want to be on (or
>   off), lets you generate and send MailChimp email campaigns from your
>   site, and lets you and your users view a history of emails they have
>   been sent from MailChimp. More generally, it aspires to makes your
>   email delivery world efficient and to make your user's email receipt
>   and control simple and precise. Thanks to [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/)'s ongoing
>   sponsorship, this module is actively maintained and regularly adding
>   features.