# Newsletter and email limit of provider

Tags: 6, emails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add newsletter functionality in drupal 7 (just stable modules if possible)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5570/how-to-add-newsletter-functionality-in-drupal-7-just-stable-modules-if-possible)

I need to know a good email newsletter system for Drupal that can trigger email send in batch. I know in WP how to do that, but have to previous experience with Drupal. I Have about 1000 email, and the provider allow only 200 mail / hour, so i need and option to send let's say 150 mail / hours and let the system go under the radar. Please, don't tell me to use mail-chimp, i know and it's not in Drupal but outside. i like a solution build in !

thanks in advance

Comment: I have google and found : http://drupal.org/project/mailq but have no idea if it's good or bad...

Comment: it's drupal 6, just to let you know

Comment: I have retagged your questions appropriately. In the future, make sure to do so. It will aid anyone answering your question. That being said, the answer is still the same for Drupal 6. Use the Simplenews module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to use "[MailQ](http://drupal.org/project/mailq)" (For Drupal 7 you can use "[Queue Mail](http://drupal.org/project/queue_mail)" instead) and "[Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron)" modules together.

Configure MailQ module to send 50 mails per one batch.

Configure Elysia Cron module to run MailQ cron hook every 15 minutes.
(note you need configure you cron job to run every 5 minutes or even often, more details in Elysia Cron readme.txt)

In this case MailQ will send 50 emails each 15 minutes - and you will got no more than 200 emails per hour.